# slideshow - disable left or right button based on position

Tags: javascript

I have coded a small slideshow script, which scrolls left and right.

I am hoping for some advice or guidance; as I am stuck for inspiration or a possible solution.

How would you identify if you are at the beginning or end, to respectively disable the left or right button?

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let one = new slideShow('merchandising');
})

function slideShow(element) {

  this.scrollContainer = document.getElementById(element);
  this.scrollLeft = this.scrollContainer.getElementsByClassName('left')[0];
  this.scrollRight = this.scrollContainer.getElementsByClassName('right')[0];

  this.move = (amount) => {
    this.scrollContainer.scrollLeft += amount;
  }

  this.scrollLeft.addEventListener('click', () => {
    this.move(-225);
  })

  this.scrollRight.addEventListener('click', () => {
    this.move(225)
  })

}
```

```css
#merchandising {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.slot {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.left { display: block; position: absolute; left: 0; }
.right { display: block; position: absolute; right: 0; }
```

```html
<div id='merchandising'>
  <button class='left'>left</button>
  <button class='right'>right</button>
  <div class='slot'>one</div>
  <div class='slot'>two</div>
  <div class='slot'>three</div>
  <div class='slot'>four</div>
  <div class='slot'>five</div>
  <div class='slot'>six</div>
  <div class='slot'>seven</div>
  <div class='slot'>eight</div>
  <div class='slot'>nine</div>
  <div class='slot'>ten</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check on right click function like **((this.scrollContainer.scrollLeft + this.scrollContainer.offsetWidth) == this.scrollContainer.scrollWidth)**

I hope this snippet will help you lot.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let one = new slideShow('merchandising');
})

function slideShow(element) {

  this.scrollContainer = document.getElementById(element);
  this.scrollLeft = this.scrollContainer.getElementsByClassName('left')[0];
  this.scrollRight = this.scrollContainer.getElementsByClassName('right')[0];

  this.move = (amount) => {
    this.scrollContainer.scrollLeft += amount;
  }

  this.scrollLeft.addEventListener('click', () => {
    this.move(-225);
    document.getElementsByClassName('right')[0].classList.remove('hide');
    if (this.scrollContainer.scrollLeft === 0) {
      document.getElementsByClassName('left')[0].classList.remove('previous');
    }
  })

  this.scrollRight.addEventListener('click', () => {
    this.move(225);
    document.getElementsByClassName('right')[0].classList.remove('hide');
    if (this.scrollContainer.scrollLeft > 0) {
      document.getElementsByClassName('left')[0].classList.add('previous');
      if((this.scrollContainer.scrollLeft + this.scrollContainer.offsetWidth)  == this.scrollContainer.scrollWidth){
        document.getElementsByClassName('right')[0].classList.add('hide');
      }
    }
  })
}
```

```css
#merchandising {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.slot {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.left { 
    display: none; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0; 
}
.left.previous {
  display: block;
}
.right { 
    display: block; 
    position: absolute; 
    right: 0; 
}
.right.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id='merchandising'>
  <button class='left'>left</button>
  <button class='right'>right</button>
  <div class='slot'>one</div>
  <div class='slot'>two</div>
  <div class='slot'>three</div>
  <div class='slot'>four</div>
  <div class='slot'>five</div>
  <div class='slot'>six</div>
  <div class='slot'>seven</div>
  <div class='slot'>eight</div>
  <div class='slot'>nine</div>
  <div class='slot'>ten</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much, I've learnt something new today, many many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Its not the complete logic for a slider but i think you get the idea :)

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let one = new slideShow('merchandising');
})

function slideShow(element) {

  this.scrollContainer = document.getElementById(element);
  this.scrollLeft = this.scrollContainer.getElementsByClassName('left')[0];
  this.scrollRight = this.scrollContainer.getElementsByClassName('right')[0];

  this.move = (amount) => {
    this.scrollContainer.scrollLeft += amount;
  }

  this.scrollLeft.addEventListener('click', () => {
    this.move(-225);
    if (this.scrollContainer.scrollLeft === 0) {
      document.getElementsByClassName('left')[0].classList.remove('previous');
    }
  })

  this.scrollRight.addEventListener('click', () => {
    this.move(225)
    if (this.scrollContainer.scrollLeft > 0) {
      document.getElementsByClassName('left')[0].classList.add('previous');
    }
  })

}
```

```css
#merchandising {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.slot {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.left { display: none; position: absolute; left: 0; }

.left.previous {
  display: block;
}
.right { display: block; position: absolute; right: 0; }
```

```html
<div id='merchandising'>
  <button class='left'>left</button>
  <button class='right'>right</button>
  <div class='slot'>one</div>
  <div class='slot'>two</div>
  <div class='slot'>three</div>
  <div class='slot'>four</div>
  <div class='slot'>five</div>
  <div class='slot'>six</div>
  <div class='slot'>seven</div>
  <div class='slot'>eight</div>
  <div class='slot'>nine</div>
  <div class='slot'>ten</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner I know thats why i said thats not the complete logic but i thought you can work on it further now or is the answer not enough for you?

Comment: @YalcinKilic thank you very much for your assistance, it is very much appreciated. It certainly helped to evolve my thinking. Might I be so bold as to ask, how would you get the end coordinate to disable the right button? I have tried ```getBoundingClientRect``` with left, right, x and width, nothing seems to work